# Determining the exact posterior distribution

Tags: bayesian, posterior, conjugate-prior

I am trying to find the exact posterior distribution from a prior that has the form

$$ p(\theta) = [cos(4\pi\theta) + 1]^2$$

and the likelihood has the form

$$ p(D|\theta) = \theta^n(1 - \theta)^{(N-n)}$$ where D is the data.

So far what I've got is

$$ p(\theta|D) = p(\theta)p(D|\theta) $$
$$ p(\theta|D) =  [cos(4\pi\theta) + 1]^2 * \theta^n(1 - \theta)^{(N-n)} $$
$$ p(\theta|D) = [cos^2(4\pi\theta) + 2cos(4\pi\theta) + 1] \theta^n(1 - \theta)^{(N-n)}$$

What I don't understand is how do we know when a likelihood function can have a conjugate prior? Also, if $$p(\theta)$$ is the conjugate prior, can someone please finish the proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) the correct relation is$$p(\theta|D)\propto p(\theta)p(D|\theta)$$ie there is a multiplicative constant missing (b) starting with a given prior means it is not necessarily conjugate. And indeed it is not in the current case since the posterior does not look like the prior...

Comment: Likelihood has a [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) if it comes from the [exponential family of distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

Comment: @Tim if the prior comes from the exponential family of distributions or the likelihood?

Comment: Likelihood. Otherwise, this would need to imply that if you have a prior from exponential family (say Gaussian) it's conjugate for anything.

Comment: @Tim so I have a likelihood that has a bernoulli distribution (it is in the exponential family of distributions), so by what you are saying, the prior is a conjugate. On the other hand, Xi'an in his comment, is saying that because the posterior does not look like the prior, the prior is not conjugate...

Comment: This is not what I said. I said that there are conjugate priors for exponential family distributions. Not every prior would be conjugate for them. For Bernoulli, the beta distribution is a conjugate prior.

Comment: @Tim Understood. Thank you.